# How to add space between numbers, with DisplayFormat

Tags: string, delphi, mask, reportbuilder

How can I add spaces between numbers with **DisplayFormat**.

Like this example:

```
50130301037855000150550010000000131000000132
```

I'm need this:

```
5013 0301 0378 5500 0150 5500 1000 0000 1310 0000 0132
```

Anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer using **DisplayFormat**

```
9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999;0;
```

Thanks all.

Comment: What data type are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can not format like that just using the DisplayFormat property, but you can rely on the OnGetText event to make this happen.

I'm assuming your field is of string type, for example:

```
function InsertBlankEach4Chars(S: string): string;
begin
  Result := '';
  while S <> '' do
  begin
    Result := Result + Copy(S, 1, 4) + ' ';
    Delete(S, 1, 4);
  end;
  Result := Trim(Result);
end;

procedure TMyForm.MyQueryFieldGetText(Sender: TField;
  var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  if DisplayText then
    Text := InsertBlankEach4Chars(Sender.AsString)
  else
    Text := Sender.AsString;
end;
```

<sub>**Disclaimer**: This code was written in the browser and is not tested. If you're going to use this in a time-sensitive process, I warn you this function may be optimized for better performance.</sub>

Comment: That's not how the `<sub>` tag is supposed to be used, but I can't argue about the result...

Comment: Note: You could use the DisplayText property if the field type is integer or largeInt. Just set it to `0000 0000 0000 0000 ...`.

Comment: I think it's the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you wnt to use it for currency then use this .

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var  a :Currency;
begin
ThousandSeparator :=' ';
if edit1.Text <>'' then  a:=strtofloat(edit1.Text) else a:=0;
edit2.Text :=FloatToStrF(a,ffNumber, 12, 2);
end;
```